# Efficiently Banning IPs Using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ip

```
CREATE TABLE `banned_ip` (
  `id` INT( 25 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
  `ip` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL , 
  `reason` TEXT NOT NULL )
```

**Config.php**

```
    <?php
// config
$config['host'] = "localhost"; // host name of your mysql server
$config['user'] = "username"; // your mysql username
$config['pass'] = "password"; // your mysql password
$config['db'] = "database"; // the database your table is in.

// the @ sign is an error supressor, meaning we can use our own error messages, this connects and selects db
@mysql_connect("$config[host]","$config[user]","$config[pass]") 
    or die("There was an error connecting to the database, MySql said:<br />".mysql_error()."");
@mysql_select_db("$config[db]") 
    or die("There was an error connecting to the database, MySql said:<br />".mysql_error()."");
?>
```

Ban.php

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$find_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned_ip WHERE ip='$ip'"); 
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($find_ip); 
if($ip == $ban['ip']){ 
    die("You are banned from this site!");
else {
    echo "Your Were not Banned";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(ip) VALUES('$ip')";
} 
?>
```

What I am doing is check my database for a ip , if it is banned or not. IF not banned, Showing him message "Your Were not Banned" and banning him.

Storing his ip in database. And then if he comes again on site, is will be show "You are banned from this site!"

By this i am giving each ip only one time access to my content. Is this script efficeint enough? This script is not working for me. It is not banning my ip , instead it keeps showing me my content.

Comment: Don't ban by IP.  Doing so will cause every user on a school, business, or home network, all of whom are usually behind NATs or outbound firewalls, to be blocked when a user becomes banned.

Comment: Don't NOT ban by IP but do so only when there is repeated abuse or ban evasion detected.

Comment: There isn't a fully reliable method, but you can narrow it a little by combining user-agent with IP. Any method you choose can be circumvented by crafty users unless you ban their user accounts entirely.

Comment: My requirement is to ban ip, giving only one time access to visitor. Please give me some code help.

Comment: btw it's no longer recommended to use the mysql_ functions. Please use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: There seems to be a missing curly brace in your IF...ELSE. Not sure if that would make a difference (my hunch is that it would cause a FATAL error anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with different tables obviously. You do a select query for banned_ip, to check if the IP is banned. But if he is not banned, you try to insert into the user table. This way you do note down all banned IPs, but you don't select them.

Also, when you query the database, it's bad behaviour to do SELECT *. Select only the values you need (in this case it doesn't even matter what, since you check if he finds an row for the ip).

There's never a 100% sure way to prevent non-logged-in users from accessing content. If you ban an IP, you might ban several persons at once (like schools). Using cookies (and also Sessions) is not efficient enough, since the cookie can be deleted.

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$find_ip = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM banned_ip WHERE ip='$ip'"); 
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($find_ip); 
if($ip == $ban['ip']){ 
    die("You are banned from this site!");
else {
    echo "Your Were not Banned";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO banned_ip (ip) VALUES('$ip')";
} 
?>
```

Comment: This isn't a side where you ask for code and people start working for you. You do realize that you'll have to set up a database for this code to work? This won't magically ban ips if there aren't corresponding tables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.I am unable to understand your answer. Thanks for help though

Comment: Updated my answer. Since I don't know how your database actually looks like, this is just guessing.

Comment: Look, just make sure that the table you are searching the ip in, is also the table in which you insert your banned ip into. No big deal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php> include "connect_to_mysql.php";
$proxy_headers = array(
    'HTTP_VIA',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED',
    'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
    'VIA',
    'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'FORWARDED_FOR',
    'X_FORWARDED',
    'FORWARDED',
    'CLIENT_IP',
    'FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
    'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION'
   );
   foreach($proxy_headers as $x){
    if (isset($_SERVER[$x])) die("You are using a proxy!");
   }

     $counter = 1873;
    $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "sorry_search.php";
   $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;

 $dynamicList="";
 $dynamicListaa="";
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip LIKE '%54.36.%'");
 $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
 if ($productCount > 0) {
    // get all the product details
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $product_name = $row["ip"];
        $counter++;

  $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bannedIp (bannedip_id, bannedip) VALUES ('".$counter."', '".$product_name."')") or die(mysql_error());
  echo $sql2;
   print($product_name);

     }

     } else {
     header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
     }


 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$find_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bannedIp WHERE bannedip='$ip'"); 
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($find_ip); 
if($ip == $ban['bannedip']){ 
 die("You are banned from this site2!");
 }

$ip_parts = explode (".", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$parts = $ip_parts[0] . $ip_parts[1];
if($parts == 5436)
{
 die("You are banned from this site1!");
 }
 <?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks for answering the question. I think it would be a bit more help if you elaborate it a bit to explain in word what was the problem and what should be done differently.